# plotting time series data using matplotlib python

Tags: python, time-series, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize Time series data is as follows [image]

following is my code to plot the data

`plt.plot(data['date'], data['c_16_avg_a'])`

`plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')`

the date is getting truncated here. and the plot looks wired.

Any suggestions will greatly be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Are your values sorted by the date (increasing)? If not `matplotlib` will simply go in the order the values are provided (i.e. go forwards and backwards) in time.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the dates in your column are **not sorted**. To fix this either sort the values by the date column or, even better, plot using the **timestamps** instead of their dates. Matplotlib inherently handles datetime format better than it does datest represented as strings!

The best option however, is to add the timestamps as the dataframe's index and use `pd.Series.plot()` instead of matplotlib.

```py
data.index = data['time_stamp']
data['c_16_avg_a'].plot()
```